# My script is not working and its giving me this specific error "Players.73737s2.PlayerScripts.LocalScript:4: attempt to index nil with 'Humanoid'"

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

local walk = 0
player.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 1
while true do
wait(1)
player.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = walk
walk = walk + 1
end
```

for some unknown reason it gives me error Players.73737s2.PlayerScripts.LocalScript:4: attempt to index nil with 'Humanoid'

Comment: well, `player.Character` is nil. Are you sure it is fully loaded?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Characters can take some time to load depending on a few factors. During this time the character will appear nil until the character is fully loaded.
You can do this two ways either with a function or a repeat wait.

**Function**

```
local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer -- Script is hopefully in a Client Side area.

Player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(Character)
-- Your code here.
end)
```

**Waiting**

```
local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer -- Script is hopefully in a Client Side area.

repeat wait() until Player.Character
-- Your Code
```

I hope this helps and I apologize for the lack of formatting in my answer as I am still learning StackOverflow, If I said anything wrong I will attempt to correct my issue.

Comment: Nice answer! Though you should discourage the waiting way of doing it. Kampfkarren (reputable person) [has explained](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/avoiding-wait-and-why/244015) it very well.