# How to fix the "attempt to index nil with 'PrimaryPart'

Tags: indexing, lua, null, roblox

local hitTarg = hb(Vector3.new(4,6,4), character.PrimaryPart.CFrame * Cframe.new(0,0,-3) {character}, character)

The error is "attempt to index nil with "PrimaryPart""

I can't find anything that can help me fix this

And thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My script is not working and its giving me this specific error "Players.73737s2.PlayerScripts.LocalScript:4: attempt to index nil with 'Humanoid'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74434028/my-script-is-not-working-and-its-giving-me-this-specific-error-players-73737s2)

Comment: Can you show us how you set the variable character as that is where the error seems to lie

Comment: It seems like the character variable is nil. How was that variable defined?